# How many MongoDB Collections required

Tags: mongodb

I am just starting with MongoDB, So please help me decide how many collection and collection fields will be required to implement below functionality.

[image]

Here I have total five images with their respective title and description which will be managed by Admin of the website. So I need to keep all the image urls, titles and descriptions and pagID in mongodb, So how many collections and their fields I will be required to achieve this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read about MongoDB data modelling [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/).

You could use just `one collection` for the functionality you have stated.

Sample document would be like :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('fe67543457687798ab12'),
    url: 'www.example.com/img/qwerty.jpg',
    title: 'Image 1',
    description: 'Description 1',
    pagID: 'some ID'
}
```

Comment: I just want to know can keep position of image like top left or left or something also?

Comment: Yes, you can. Add another field `position: 'top'` in your document.